# VS2008 debugger shows incorrect values. How to clean/reset/fix the debugger?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, qt4, visual-studio-debugging, memory-corruption

My VS2008 debugger show corrupted values for almost for all the variables. I know it is not correct since I just printed those values which gives me correct values.

Here are some of those bogus values,
[image]
[image]

but meantime in the consol prints,

[image]

So, I don't get what is wrong here. But I think the issue should be with the Visual Studio. Anyone knows how to fix this ?

Updated: This is a Qt application.And Here are the things I have tried:

- Rebuilt all the projects
- Deleted debug folder and rebuilt
- Got a fresh copy from git repo and rebuilt
- Installed SP1 and all the C++ related updates/hotfixes for VS2008

Comment: Are you compiling on Release configuration?

Comment: @idanuda nope. It is debug

Comment: did you try to delete the entire Debug folder?

Comment: @idanuda yes, after you asked. Still same, shows bogus values.

Comment: What difference does it make that it is a Qt application?  Is there some code in the debugger that says "if the application is a Qt app, show bogus values"?  Can you duplicate the issue with a brand new, simple application?  If no, then the problem is not the debugger.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You can't be serious, what is wrong with providing some   information regarding the environment ? And no, I'm afraid I can't simplify the code since it is a large solution.

Comment: @Morpheus - I am serious.  What would make a debugger work properly for one set of C++ code, but not for another set of C++ code?  It either works or it doesn't, regardless of the application.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Please, just try to help this poor guy instead of talking about something (whether I need to mention Qt there or not) which is not relevant to the question. Thank you.

Comment: I asked a simple question -- does this problem appear in other applications?  Yes or no.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie no, it does not appear. So is this the way you asking that  ? **"Is there some code in the debugger that says "if the application is a Qt app, show bogus values"?"** I'm sorry, but what kind of question is that ? You could simply asked that question like that in your latest comment. "does this problem appear in other applications?" No offence.

Comment: If it doesn't appear in other applications, then some setting in this particular application could be compiling with optimizations turned on.  There is nothing stopping a project from having optimizations enabled and still be a "debug" version.  Please check all of the projects you're building, and look at the "Optimizations" setting, and not whether it is a "Debug" or "Release" build.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie awesome. Yes, it was fixed when I turned off all the optimizations. Thanks. Love you :)

Comment: OK.  I'll put it as an answer, just in case others have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the issue doesn't appear in non-Qt apps, then some setting in this particular application could be compiling with optimizations turned on.

It gets confusing in Visual Studio, but nothing stops a "Debug" build to have optimizations turned on, and a "Release" build to have optimizations turned off (more often, you will see Release builds with optimizations turned off).

On top of that, it is possible to have a "Debug" build that cannot be debugged due to the debug symbols not being produced (two more settings in the Project turns on/off symbols during compilation and linking).  In other words, any combination of "debugging on/off" and "optimizations on/off" is possible in "Release" and "Debug" build configurations.

Since you are producing symbols, the issue won't be that the symbols aren't being produced.  Therefore, please check all of the projects you're building, and look at the "Optimizations" setting, and not whether the configuration is named  "Debug" or "Release".

Comment: **from msdn**
When the compiler optimizes code, it repositions and reorganizes instructions, resulting in more efficient compiled code. Because of this rearrangement, the debugger cannot always identify the source code that corresponds to a set of instructions.
Optimization can affect:
Local variables, which can be removed by the optimizer or moved to locations the debugger does not understand.
Positions inside a function, which are changed when the optimizer merges blocks of code.
Function names for frames on the call stack, which may be wrong if the optimizer merges two functions.